# Module did not self register with Talib and AVA

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, ava, ta-lib

I'm getting a `Module did not self register` error I am unable to get rid of using [talib](https://github.com/oransel/node-talib) and [ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava).

I have tried Node 8.9.0 as well as 9.0.0, upgraded AVA and tried stable and dev branches of talib. I am running test serially as well. And of course I have cleared and rebuilt my `node_modules` folder - this is evidently not a case of changing node versions like I have seen posted.

Test:

```
test.serial( t => {
 const talib = require('talib') 
})
test.serial( t => {
 const talib = require('talib') 
})
```

The first test works but more than one throws that error. In the past I have had success clearing modules with [clear-module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/clear-module) and [import-fresh](https://github.com/sindresorhus/import-fresh) but not this time.

```
const clear = require('clear-module')
const fresh = require('import-fresh')
test.serial(t => {
  clear.all('talib')
  const talib = fresh('talib')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where that error comes from, but one thing to keep in mind is that AVA starts running your tests asynchronously, e.g. not when the file is first loaded. Do you need to require `talib` outside of `test.serial()`?

Comment: I could do that yes but then my code doesn't "reset" between tests. I normally use import-fresh to reload and for stubborn things like node-config I use clear-module but this one proves difficult. I've had some potential success (not confirmed) by requiring talib right at the moment I use it in the code (i.e. inline). I guess I would like to understand the workings behind this error - I usually see it in conjunction with node version incompatibility. It's a node-gyp thing I am pretty sure but don't know if this can be fixed.